# Authorization header is not received correctly in the backend Angular 10 + Spring Boot

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to pass a JWT token in the 'Authorization' header of my angular requests to my Spring Boot Backend.

But my Spring Back and does not see the token in the header, this results to cors errors..
When I check the headers from my request the token is set in the 'Authorization' header:

[image]

My JWTRequestFilter from Spring Boot:

```
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Autowired
    public JwtRequestFilter(JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService, JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.jwtUserDetailsService = jwtUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        // JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
        // only the Token
        if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(request.toString());
            System.out.println(requestTokenHeader);
            logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
        }

        // Once we get the token validate it.
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
            // authentication
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                        .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
                // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
                // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

When I print the `requestTokenHeader` is print null... and it also print the message in the print statement below...

[image]

Below is my `JWTinterceptor.ts` where I set the header:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private localStorage: LocalStorageManagerService) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        // add auth header with jwt if user is logged in and request is to the api url
        const currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
        const isLoggedIn = currentUser && this.localStorage.getToken();
        const isApiUrl = request.url.startsWith(environment.apiUrl);
        if (isLoggedIn && isApiUrl) {
            console.log(this.localStorage.getToken());
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${this.localStorage.getToken()}`
                }
            });
        }

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it happening in a local environment or production ? I think your code looks fine, but maybe there is a WAF or something like that filtering out attributes of your header.

Comment: You might replace the OncePerRequestFilter with a BasicAuthenticationFilter

Comment: hi @JuanBC it is happening in a local environment...